# jersey cross domain request

Tags: java, jersey, cors, basic-authentication

I am using jersey 2.18 for developing rest api. (using tomcat container)

I want to allow access to clients from other domain.

So I am trying below code to allow cross domain requests.

***Filter***

```
public class MyCorsFilter implements Filter {

    public MyCorsFilter() { }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException { }

    public void destroy() { }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException  {
      ((HttpServletResponse)response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

***web.xml***

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyCorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>MyCorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyCorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Above code works fine until I add HTTP basic authentication.

When I add basic authentication I am getting following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When checked headers using developer tools I found following:

[image]

Please note that the error is while executing `OPTIONS` method. (I am using `GET` method)

Any suggestion on how to add allow CORS with basic HTTP authentication will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Catalina CORS filter configurations in your web.xml as below -

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puneet is right.

Take note you will probably have to setup some parameters, namely :

- cors.allowed.origins
- cors.allowed.methods
- cors.allowed.headers
- cors.exposed.headers

Answer (score 0):

Actually browser makes preflight request before your actuall request with http request method "options" . so you have to send 200 OK to this request and allow cross domain header like

```
 httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE,PUT");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Authorization, Content-Type");
    if(httpRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")){
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        return;
    }
```

More information you can find at http://enable-cors-org/