# Angular 2 : PUT and DELETE request change to OPTIONS

Tags: angular, rest, http, jersey-2.0

I need some help, I don't know how but all my `http.put` and `http.delete` request from my angular's client are changing in `http.options`.
The only error that I have is:

```
ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown …", error: error }
```

If someone has an idea, thanks to answer me.

Have a nice day

```
let header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  });
  this.http
          .put('http://localhost:1993/pays/'+this.codeNouveauPays, JSON.stringify(""), {
                headers : header,
                params : new HttpParams().set('nom', this.nomNouveauPays).set('code', this.codeNouveauPays)
            })
          .subscribe();
```

Comment: Check if you have a problem of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), it might be involved in the problem.

Comment: could you share http call code.

Comment: @bracco23 I haven't find solutions for a http grizzly server

Comment: Read up on CORS and the browser same-domain policy. Browsers will send an initial OPTIONS request to any domain outside of their own. This OPTIONS request is called a "pre-flight" and is requesting information from the server pertaining to what domains (origins) and methods are allowed access to that HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @jjones how can i allow access? I don't find

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers, not request headers.

Comment: @Quentin I've tried with and without, it does work

Comment: @TobiasZelft you need an OPTIONS route that has those headers on the response... This must be done on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your requests are not changed to OPTIONS requests, that's the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

The error you get is because your server (your API) has an error when receiving the preflight request.

Because the preflight request fails, your actual request (DELETE or PUT) on the same endpoint is never done.

A solution to implement preflight handling in jersey can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372999/4102561).

Comment: I try it, and it doesn't work

Comment: @TobiasZelft — Then (1) Use the Network tab to look at exactly what requests and responses are being made (2) Figure out which one of the requests is getting the wrong response (3) Look at the (server side!) code you wrote to make that response and try to fix it (4) Failing that, ask a new question with a [mcve]